# {"code":29000,"message":"signature doesn't match"}

Tags: php, api, curl, signature

Hello there I have a problem that I haven't solved for 2 days

Api Requirements : https://kickecosystem.github.io/KickEx-API-beta/index.html#introduction

my codes :

```
public function __construct ($apiKey, $apiSecret)
    {
        $this->apiKey    = $apiKey;
        $this->apiSecret = $apiSecret;
        $this->baseUrl   = 'https://gate.kickex.com/api/v1/';
    }


private function call ($method, $params = array(), $apiKey = false)
{
    $uri  = $this->baseUrl.$method;

    $timestamp = time();
    $body = "";
    $method2 = "GET";
    $request_path = '/api/v1/user/balance';
    $sign = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha512", $this->apiSecret,
    hash_hmac("sha512", $body, 
        hash_hmac("sha512", $request_path, 
            hash_hmac("sha512", $method2, $timestamp, true),
        true),
    true),
true));

    $ch = curl_init ($uri);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('KICK-API-KEY: '.$this->apiKey, 'KICK-API-PASS: '.base64_encode("cencoredmypass"), 'KICK-API-TIMESTAMP: '.$timestamp , 'Content-Type: application/json', 'User-Agent: qwe', 'KICK-SIGNATURE: '.$sign));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); // Do Not Cache
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //if ($result != true) {
    //  throw new \Exception (curl_error($ch));
    //}

    return $result;
}

//method : user/balance

public function getBalances ()
    {
        return $this->call ('user/balance', true);
    }
```

my .php result :

```
{"code":29000,"message":"signature doesn't match"}
```

all keys are correct.. Where could I be doing wrong

Comment: I see that you're feeding a hardcoded value `$request_path = '/api/v1/user/balance';` into the signature, but the actual request path you use is coming from your `$method` parameter. Do those match? Is `$method` equal to `user/balance`?

Comment: $uri  = $this->baseUrl.$method;
$uri = https://gate.kickex.com/api/v1//api/v1/user/balance;
$request_path = '/api/v1/user/balance';
$method  = user/balance yes its match

Comment: That URI seems wrong though: `$uri = gate.kickex.com/api/v1//api/v1/user/balance`, the `/api/v1/` part is duplicated.

Comment: I wrote wrong here, the real code is not like that
real code : $uri  = $this->baseUrl.$method;   ====>>>> result ===>>>> gate.kickex.com/api/v1/user/balance    there is no problem here thanks

Comment: I can't see any errors in your logic. You might want to contact KickEx to try and help you debug this.